# How to flip any bit in a memory block?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

How can I flip any bit I want in a chunk of memory:

```
int size = 4000;
void* block = malloc(size);
bzero(block, size);
// flip bit #100 in block
```

Thanks

Comment: `std::vector<bool> vb(4000*CHAR_BIT); vb[317] = false;`

Comment: How are the bits in your chunk of memory numbered ?  One could assume that bit 0, is 2^0 in byte 0, bit 1 is 2^1 in byte 0 and so on... But of the chunk of memory is treated, say, as an array of unsigned integer, then how you number the bits may depend on the ended-ness of the processor (or the data).  One tends to assume that `CHAR_BIT == 8`... but, technically, that's just an assumption (though late-model POSIX does require it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void flip_bit (void *block, int bit)
{
    unsigned char *b = (unsigned char *) block;
    b[bit/8] ^= 1 << (bit % 8);
}
```